# Why did Gemini Planet Imager hardly detect anything?

Tags: observational-astronomy, exoplanet

GPI was originally thought able to directly image tens of planets but [so far has only discovered one new planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_Planet_Imager#Achievements)?

Why is this?

---

From [Gemini Observatory; Adaptive optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemini_Observatory#Adaptive_optics)

[image: Gemini Science Image posted on Gemini Observatory web page, 13 August 2015]

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:GPI-im.jpg)

Comment: Just the one is extremely impressive IMO.  The angualar separation is tiny.

Comment: The Gemini Planet Imager Exoplanet Survey has, halfway through its total sample of 600 stars, detected a total of six planets (and three brown dwarfs), although most of these had been previously identified in earlier, smaller studies (https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2019AJ....158...13N/abstract).

Comment: Can you say where you saw that the GPI would *discover* tens of new planets (as opposed to directly imaging tens of planets, which is obviously something different)?

Comment: @ProfRob It was years ago. I may have misremembered.